# Is there a way to dynamically add pages to react-pdf/renderer

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-pdf

I want to create a pdf that takes in a json and displays a service report like pdf file. I have been able to successfully create the page using this code:

```
return (
    
    <Document>
 <Page size="A4" style={styles.page} object-fit="fill">
        <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'column',justifyContent:"space-between"}}> 
        <View>
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
        <View style={styles.section}>
        <Image style={styles.image} src={{ uri:Logo, method: "GET", headers: { "Cache-Control": "no-cache" }, body: "" }} />  
        <Text style={{paddingLeft:5}}>Air Conditioning</Text>
        </View>
        </View>
        </View>
  </Page>

</Document>
```

The JSON Format I have is this:

```
{"before":["image-1.jpg","image-2.jpg"],"after":["image-8.jpg","image-23.jpg"]}
```

I want to generate the images dynamically and if they do not fit, I want to create a page and fit the others. The code below is supposed to put before and after pairs next to each other and under each other like this:

```
before   after
before   after
-- page break --
before   after
     after
-- page break--
```

I wrote the following code with the help of an AI:

```
 {data.before.map(( index) => {
        if (index % 2 === 0) {
          return (
            <Page size="A4" style={styles.page_ss} key={`${index / 2}_before_after`}>
              {data.before.slice(index, index + 2).map((image, innerIndex) => (
                <View style={styles.container_ss} key={`before_${innerIndex}`}>
                  <Image src={`${ImageURLMain}/${image}`} style={styles.image_ss} />
                  <Text>Before</Text>
                </View>
              ))}
              {data.after.slice(index, index + 2).map((image, innerIndex) => (
                <View style={styles.container_ss} key={`after_${innerIndex}`}>
                  <Image src={`${ImageURLMain}/${image}`} style={styles.image_ss} />
                  <Text>After</Text>
                </View>
              ))}
            </Page>
          );
        }

      })}
```

I tried inserting it as shown in the following:

```
const data= {"before":["image-1.jpg","image-2.jpg"],"after":["image-8.jpg","image-23.jpg"]}

return (
    
    <Document>
 <Page size="A4" style={styles.page} object-fit="fill">
        <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'column',justifyContent:"space-between"}}> 
        <View>
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
        <View style={styles.section}>
        <Image style={styles.image} src={{ uri:Logo, method: "GET", headers: { "Cache-Control": "no-cache" }, body: "" }} />  
        <Text style={{paddingLeft:5}}>Air Conditioning LLC</Text>
        </View>
        </View>
        </View>
  </Page>

{data.before.map(( index) => {
        if (index % 2 === 0) {
          return (
            <Page size="A4" style={styles.page_ss} key={`${index / 2}_before_after`}>
              {data.before.slice(index, index + 2).map((image, innerIndex) => (
                <View style={styles.container_ss} key={`before_${innerIndex}`}>
                  <Image src={`${ImageURLMain}/${image}`} style={styles.image_ss} />
                  <Text>Before</Text>
                </View>
              ))}
              {data.after.slice(index, index + 2).map((image, innerIndex) => (
                <View style={styles.container_ss} key={`after_${innerIndex}`}>
                  <Image src={`${ImageURLMain}/${image}`} style={styles.image_ss} />
                  <Text>After</Text>
                </View>
              ))}
            </Page>
          );
        }

      })}

</Document>
```

But I either get an empty page or I just get the first page only.

Is it possible to add pages dynamically and if so how can I efficiently do it with the JSON format I have.

Note that I have not added the full code on this question. I added the minimum to reproduce the errors I am facing.